# my android app some times display half of the screen only when maximize

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flash-cs6

I am using the scale-mode, alignment and aspect-ratio like this in flash cs6.

stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;

stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

Aspect Ratio : landscape

When my app is maximized(after minimize) some times it will display half of the screen only. In some devices user logged out.

Comment: scalemode has to be noscale on mobile devices.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
Then how can we fit the screen to the any android device.

Comment: you write code to check for screen size, dpi, then you display content accordingly. If you think you can put a app together for mobile and it's magically gonna fit all screen size you will be disappointed.

Comment: @BotMaster Can you elaborate why scaleMode "has to be" NO_SCALE? Certainly it's the most flexible route (to apply your own scaling logic) but are you sure the reported issue is even related to this? I've seen even native Android apps exhibit this behavior.

Comment: it has to do with the way stage size is reported, with any value other than noscale the stage size is reported incorrectly and there will be no way to show your content correctly.

Comment: @BotMaster That's the way it's supposed to work, though. `EXACT_FIT` is supposed to report the original SWF dimensions and let the runtime scale to fill the actual stage viewport. Obviously something is going wrong here, but it's not clear to me what.

Comment: using anything other than noscale for mobile development is a crappy shortcut for lazy developers that only contributes to the bad reputation of anything done in Flash. I would not recommend any app done that way.

Comment: @BotMaster You have a strong opinion. :) I partially agree, but really I'm just interested in learning what the actual problem here is. On mobile you don't have to use `NO_SCALE` but perhaps there is a bug related to other scale modes.

Comment: @BotMaster  I am new for mobile development. Can you provide sample code to fit all android devices screens. Otherwise provide some links which is useful for me.

Comment: there's no sample code that would fit here, it's an entire system. I developed myself a StageContext system that calculate pixels density, screen size ratio and fit any screen ios or Android. You got to develop your own.

Comment: Hi @BotMaster, the problem is I am not add the movieclips to scaled movieclip. When add the all movieclips to scaled movieclip, it was fixed. Thank you for your support :)